# angular2 asynchronous function executation

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I want to execute two statements together, but not in asynchronous. Is there a way to execute `function 1` first before `function 2` in angular2?

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed. Your question doesn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 1):

We may need more info but let say you have 2 http calls and you want make them "synchronous" (one first and then the second one).
I would recommend using [ReactiveX JavaScript](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs), you can import by including:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/mergeMap';
```

With mergeMap operator you are able to start a "second task" (new [observable](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html)) taking the first one's result as input.

So, for instance, I need to check address before updating my user profile. I have 2 http calls; one for the address check and another one for updating the user profile, so I would do:

```
this.http.get(geolocationGoogleUrl, this._customAddress)
    .mergeMap((location: any)=>{ // First http response
        console.log(location);
        // Do your stuff before second call

        return this.http.patch(patchUrl, localAddress); // Use frist http response as input
    }).subscribe((updatedUser)=>{ // Second http response
        this._user = updatedUser;
    });
```

As you noticed, you need to subscribe to a observable in order to trigger the call.